# Selenium send_keys doesn't work if input type="number"

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing tests using selenium. In those tests I need to enter a number into a field in a form.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <input type="number" id="field_id">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

And the code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('file:///home/my_username/test.html')
field = browser.find_element_by_id('field_id')
field.send_keys('12')  # NOTHING HAPPEN!
```

BTW, if I change the type of the field to "text" for example there is no problem at all. In addition, `field.send_keys(Keys.UP)` work great (but doesn't work when I'm using bootstrap) and `field.clear()` work all the time, as well as `field.click()`.

Selenium version: 2.41.0
Firefox version: 29.0

Comment: What if you call `send_keys` in a loop: `for x in '12': field.send_keys(x)`?

Comment: What happens if you click the field first? Also, can you manually enter values in the field?

Comment: @RobbieWareham Clicking the field manually doesn't help. `field.click()` **does** focus on the input field. `field.send_keys` also focus on the field but nothing more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are using Firefox 29. Please downgrade to Firefox 28, which is the one Selenium 2.41.0 supports to, see [CHANGES](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/CHANGES) file. Otherwise you need to wait for new Selenium updates.

Here is what I have tested working with Firefox 28:

```
from selenium import webdriver

DEMO_PAGE = '''
    data:text/html,
    <form><input type="number" id="field_id"></form>
'''

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(DEMO_PAGE)

input_number = browser.find_element_by_id('field_id')
input_number.send_keys('12')

input_number_value = input_number.get_attribute('value')
print "input_number_value = " + input_number_value
```

See also: [Selenium can't find fields with type number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23352000/1177636)

Comment: With multiple versions of firefox installed, how would I tell selenium to use a specific one?

Comment: Is there a Selenium bug report for this? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Also, it still doesn't seem to work even with Firefox 31 (tested on Sauce Labs with Linux configured).

Comment: I created an issue for this in the Selenium tracker here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7809

Answer (score 5):

I'm on Fedora (which doesn't provide old versions of packages like Firefox) so "downgrade Firefox" is a bit of a non-answer.

Luckily, [an answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23414814/399367) hints at a better solution -- setting the "dom.forms.number" Firefox preference to disable special treatment of `input type="number"`. In Python:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()                                    
profile.set_preference("dom.forms.number", False)                       
browsers = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Working with Firefox 29 and Selenium 2.41.0

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem this morning.  After upgrading Selenium, it now works properly.

So if you are reading this, run

```
pip install -U selenium
```

and try again.  I went from Selenium version 2.41.0 to 2.42.1 and it now works properly with Firefox 30.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Javascript to tackle this issue. The following code is in Java, but it can probably be done similarly in Python:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)webdriver)
     .ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('field_id').value='12';");
```

I had the same issue and using Javascript solved it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case selenium Send_keys work fine in this way.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
assert 'Yahoo' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('p')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys('seleniumhq' + Keys.RETURN)

browser.quit()enter code here`
```

it is the web https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue in this way:

```
locator =  <element xpath>
field = browser.find_element_by_xpath(to_unicode(**locator**,"utf-8")) 
if(field != None):
     field.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a')
     field.send_keys(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/a/78179836/5902698

In my case, I'm working on chromedriver. I have a form with an `input type = number`. When attempting to send_keys, nothing happens.

I tried `driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].value = '{text}';", element)`.
This solution writes the number BUT the form does not recognize it.

It's exactly the same as :

```py
script = f"""document.evaluate({xpath}, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.value = '{text}';"""
driver.execute_script(script)
```

I also tried an alternative `pyautogui.typewrite(text)` but it produces the same result as the previous solution.

**So I need to perform a real keyboard touch instead of the simulated one by selenium.**

I'm sorry to say that it is mandatory to install 2 libraries :
`pynput` (which requires `evdev`)
Initially, the pip install did not work, so I had to execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
pip install evdev
pip install pynput
```

**OLD** SOLUTION TLDR:

```py
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
    text = "my text"
    xpath = "//my//xpath"
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()
    keyboard = Controller()
    for char in text:
        keyboard.press(char)
        keyboard.release(char)
```

This solution doesn't works in an endless mode.

**EDIT BETTER SOLUTION**
Selenium is capable of interacting with keys.

```py
def inputNumberWithKeyboard(self, element, number):

  for digit in number:
      self.actions.click(element).send_keys(eval(f"Keys.NUMPAD{digit}")).perform()
      # if digit is 1 the command will be
      # self.actions.click(element).send_keys(eval(Keys.NUMPAD1).perform()
```