# SendKeys() doesn't work in only one field of my form

Tags: java, selenium, automation, sendkeys

I have a little problem with the `sendKeys()`. It doesn't work in only one field in my form. 
when I fill in the fields, the value of my field is not changed and the test passed without error message.

Ps: I tried to send the value `+newVariable.getDecimalPlaces()` in another field and it works.
The problem is only from this field, knowing the `XPath` is correct because I did click on it.

Anyone to help me, please! Thank you :)

```
        WebElement decimalPlacesTxtBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(AreaUtils.XPATH_DECIMAL_PLACES));
        action.doubleClick(decimalPlacesTxtBox).perform();
        decimalPlacesTxtBox.sendKeys("" +newVariable.getDecimalPlaces()); 

**The xpath :** 
    public static final String XPATH_DECIMAL_PLACES     = "//*[@id=\"floatValue\"]";
```

Comment: does the field that works have an input type of "number"?

Comment: No the field that works has a type text

Comment: certain browsers will show a different control for type of number which does not return the cursor position as a normal input would.  This can cause some quirks when the webdriver attempts to sendKeys.  (I think it'll try to place the cursor after the inputted text... but that will fail)

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, the tag of element should be "input". Eg:

`public static final String XPATH_DECIMAL_PLACES  = "//input[@id=\"floatValue\"]";`

- And then, you can try to use this code for sendkeys:

> ```
> Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
> actions.moveToElement(element);
> actions.click();
> actions.sendKeys(text);
> actions.build().perform();
> ```

- If it still doesn't work. Please show me the html of the element or screenshot the inspect of that element

Comment: The html code is : `<input id="floatValue" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="9" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-required ng-touched" ng-model="$ctrl.format.decimal" ng-change="$ctrl.decorateWithFormat()" required="true" format-decimal="" style="">`
Your code doesn't work for me :(
for the Xpath() , I did a right click() and I copied the Xpath()

Comment: Did you check input element is changed or not when you click on the datepicker?

Comment: I don't have a datepicker ! It's an input that allows to put a number with 2 buttons if you want to diminue & augment the number

Comment: And when I do a `click()` on the buttons the number change but I can't  change it with a `sendKeys()`

Comment: Which version of browser and selenium did you use? This solution may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412912/selenium-send-keys-doesnt-work-if-input-type-number

Comment: I have the v 79.0.3945.79 for chrome and for selenium 3.16.1

Answer (score 0):

If its a input box, Try setting up the value in input box with JavaScriptExecutor, where [id="floatValue"] is the CSS locator of the input field:

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.querySelectorAll('[id="floatValue"]')[0].value = \"text you want to enter\"");

In some of the text fields Selenium send keys doesn't seem to work. In my case, I was able to enter the text in the text field with help of JavaScript. Please try the above code and let me know if it works.

Comment: @ Nico Haase Updated my answer, please let me know if you have any questions regarding the same