# How to send keys to an element with type = number using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, sendkeys

I am trying to send a number to an element (a textbox) that only takes number values. This element is as follows:

Currently, I have this code (the code under this paragraph) to input a number into the element. Could anyone tell me why the number isn't showing up? Any help would be appreciated.

```
bpm = 121
inputBpm = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/mp-root/div/ ... /div[3]/div/input")
inputBpm.clear()
inputBpm.send_keys(str(bpm))
```

Edit:
Here's a visual of what I'm trying to type into (after it's been cleared)
[image: The textbox]

Here's the surrounding element:

```
<div _ngcontent-soo-c572="" class="track-bpm">
<label _ngcontent-soo-c572="" class="input-title">BPM</label>
<span _ngcontent-soo-c572="" class="input-title-info">(Beats per minute)</span>
<div _ngcontent-soo-c572="" class="input-text">
<input _ngcontent-soo-c572="" type="number" name="bpm" placeholder="0" min="0" max="999" step="0.01" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do,

```
if inputBpm.get_attribute("type")  == "number":
    inputBpm.clear()
    inputBpm.send_keys(str(bpm))
```

Or you can just find that input tag with `type = number` using XPATH.

```
input_tag = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@type, 'number')]")
inputBpm.clear()
input_tag.send_keys("9023")
```

Comment: Neither of those snippets are working for some reason. It successfully clears the textbox, but it doesn't type anything.

Here's the element again: ```<input _ngcontent-soo-c572="" type="number" name="bpm" placeholder="0" min="0" max="999" step="0.01" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">```

Comment: @chucklenut40002 I tried them on [here](http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/inputs) and they did work.

Answer (score 0):

The *`<input>`* element is have the attributes *`type="number"`*, *`min="0"`* and *`max="999"`*

```
<input _ngcontent-pxo-c572="" type="number" name="bpm" placeholder="0" min="0" max="999" step="0.01" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty">
```

---

### Solution

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  bpm = 121
  my_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng-valid.ng-touched.ng-dirty[name='bpm']")))
  my_element.click()
  my_element.clear()
  my_element.send_keys(str(bpm))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  bpm = 121
  my_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty' and @name='bpm']")))
  my_element.click()
  my_element.clear()
  my_element.send_keys(str(bpm))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: When I do either of these snippets I get a timeout error. Could I be implementing them wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm working on chromedriver. I have a form with an `input type = number`. When attempting to send_keys, nothing happens.

I tried `driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].value = '{text}';", element)`.
This solution writes the number BUT the form does not recognize it.

It's exactly the same as :

```py
script = f"""document.evaluate({xpath}, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.value = '{text}';"""
driver.execute_script(script)
```

I also tried an alternative `pyautogui.typewrite(text)` but it produces the same result as the previous solution.

**So I need to perform a real keyboard touch instead of the simulated one by selenium.**

I'm sorry to say that it is mandatory to install 2 libraries :
`pynput` (which requires `evdev`)
Initially, the pip install did not work, so I had to execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
pip install evdev
pip install pynput
```

**OLD** SOLUTION TLDR:

```py
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
    text = "my text"
    xpath = "//my//xpath"
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()
    keyboard = Controller()
    for char in text:
        keyboard.press(char)
        keyboard.release(char)
```

This solution doesn't works in an endless mode.

**EDIT BETTER SOLUTION**
Selenium is capable of interacting with keys.

```py
def inputNumberWithKeyboard(self, element, number):

  for digit in number:
      self.actions.click(element).send_keys(eval(f"Keys.NUMPAD{digit}")).perform()
      # if digit is 1 the command will be
      # self.actions.click(element).send_keys(eval(Keys.NUMPAD1).perform()
```