# Capybara/selenium-webdriver: set value to input[type="number"] does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara

With latest update to selenium webdriver 2.41.0 and Firefox 29 setting of number fields does not seem to work any more:

`fill_in "my-field", with: 1` does not do anything. Is there some way to workaround this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium send\_keys doesn't work if input type="number"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412912/selenium-send-keys-doesnt-work-if-input-type-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium 2.41.0 only offically supports to Firefox 28. Please either downgrade to Firefox 28 or wait for the new Selenium release.

Duplicates of:

[Selenium can't find fields with type number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23352000/1177636)

[Selenium send_keys doesn't work if input type=“number”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23412912/1177636)